# CiviCRM Icon Spins for Activity

Tags: wordpress, activities, activity

When one clicks the Activity tab on a contact's profile, the CiviCRM logo icon just spins and nothing happens. It does not show the activities for any contact. It used to work before.

All the extensions have been disabled. Also, I used WordPress' Troubleshooting mode by disabling all the plugins, except for CiviCRM. Themes were also changed.

There is no nothing in the error log.

Any idea how it can be fixed?

ARNOLD

Comment: Look in the browser dev tools on the network tab. When you click Activities and look at the "response" it should say the error.

Comment: can sometimes be helpful to add https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer

Answer (score 2):

It appears that one cannot have more than 61 custom field data sets. We had 80. After trimming it down to 60, I was able to view the Activities when clicking the Activities tab of a Contact. I deleted 20 rows from the civicrm_custom_group table in phpMyAdmin.

Thanks @demerit and @petednz - fuzion for the pointers. Appreciated.